# What does "two-meal" mean in "There's nothing that could get him away from that two-meal town."?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, dialogue, cinema

It's a quote from the movie "The Godfather II", Tom and Frankie's scene:

> Frankie: Did my brother go back?
>
> Tom: Yeah, don't worry.
>
> Frankie: He's ten time tougher than me-- my brother. He's old fashioned.
>
> Tom: He didn't want to go out for dinner. He just wanted to go straight home.
>
> Frankie: That's my brother. **There's nothing that could get him away from that two-meal town.** He could have been big here, could've had his own family.

English is not my native language, BTW. I think "two-meal" is an adjective to "town", but I can't understand its meaning.

Comment: It refers to a town where they roll up the sidewalks so early, you can't even find a dinner. It was common for many small towns to close shop around 2 pm. It also points to an absence of saloons, hotels, and brothels. This would probably be the implication in *The Godfather*.

Comment: Though you are right about 'two-meal' pre-modifying 'town', it is classed as an appositive noun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 'two meal' town is short of the usually expected three meals a day.

The expression is similar to another idiom which describes a town as being short of the expected number of horses :

> A very small and unremarkable town that is typically regarded as dull or boring. I can't wait to graduate high school and get out of this boring, **one-horse town!**

[Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/one+horse+town)

Note that both expressions accept a certain quality to the town - the place is not utterly destitute. It just doesn't have enough to be an attractive prospect for anyone to stay there longer than is strictly necessary.